# BOLT, CHANGE PIVOT keep breaking

Tags: honda, motorcycle

I been fighting with my Reble for about a mouth. My BOLT, CHANGE PIVOT keeps bending and breaking.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I don't see a question here. What ***exactly*** are you asking for help with? Also, I see it's a Honda Rebel, but what size is the bike? What are you doing when this part breaks? Could you edit your question and put some more detail into it, please?

Comment: A picture of the bolt in its place would be helpful, too.

Comment: Are you using the correct, original bolt or just one that fits? Bolts come in different grades...

Comment: yeah, pictures, pictures!  Maybe it's hard to describe which bolt...  so pictures could be extremely useful